# Which controller for external SAS tape drive

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas, tapedrive

We're about to buy an external LTO-4 tape drive for our HP DL380g6 server, and since SCSI is on the way out, we'll buy a SAS drive, probably the HP StoreEver LTO-4 Ultrium 1760 SAS External Tape Drive (but feel free to recommend something else).

Now we haven't got any SAS ports available, so also need to buy a controller card. Would the following controllers work (listed from cheap to expensive)? Are these cards reliable? Or would you recommend other cards?

```
Lycom PE-123e
HP Smart Array P212/Z
HP SC44Ge Host Bus Adapter
HP SC08Ge Host Bus Adapter
```

If the only thing it has to control is a single external tape drive is there any reason to go for more expensive models?

Which cable do I need?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

- Buy the tape drive bundled with a SAS controller.
- Buy the purpose-built [SC44Ge SAS controller](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12617_na/12617_na.pdf) for your server.

Don't buy anything else. I don't even know what a Lycom is :)

The tape drive will come with the right `CX4 -> SAS SFF-8088` cable or `SAS SFF-8484 -> SFF-8088` cable needed for use.

Comment: Lycom is another manufacturer of controllers.

Comment: @Ernst I'd recommend the HP SC44Ge SAS controller. The tape drive includes the cables.